# Parsing only Time using Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, time, data-transfer-objects

I have a field in my DTO class which accepts start_time and end_time as "2:00 AM"

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
#[CastWith(TimeCaster::class)]
public string $start_time; // 01:00 AM example

/**
 * @var string
 */
#[CastWith(TimeCaster::class)]
public string $end_time;
```

Can I parse this format of time using Carbon in my Caster Class

```
#[\Attribute] class TimeCaster implements Caster
{
    public function cast(mixed $value): mixed
    {
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you use `Carbon::createFromFormat`

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i A','10:00 PM')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s)
```

if you want to get only time using timestamp then

```
Carbon::parse("2021-06-26 22:00:00")->format('g:i A')
```